# Linked question is absent in "This question already has answers here" banner

Tags: support, closed-questions, duplicates

I came across this question:

[Should personal pronouns always be placed at the end of a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/96767/401123)

This question was closed eight years ago as duplicate of some other question. That question is not visible. Why is it so?

Screenshot for reference:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens for *all* old duplicate closures, look e.g. [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicate%3A1+lastactive%3A..2013-02-03) for more examples.

Back then, the duplicate banner was edited into the post itself:

[image]

You can start to [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/96767/edit) the post to see the 'source code' of the banner.

The only way to solve this is to reopen the question, and close it again as a duplicate (and edit out the original banner). We do this sometimes on Meta Stack Exchange (there are many people with [dupehammers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/295232) there); on main sites, basically only ♦ moderators can do that. But as you can see, they would have to do that on many posts. I don't think that's an option.